# AS3 - How to load and read XML file on iOS

Tags: ios, xml, actionscript-3

I'm working on simple iOS game where you have e.g. 10 levels and once you completed one the next level will unlock. I create the xml file here:

```
private function SaveProgress()
    {


        addChild(myTextField);

        var GameSaveXML:XML = 
        <LEVEL>
        <LEVEL_01>false</LEVEL_01>
        <LEVEL_02>false</LEVEL_02>
        <LEVEL_03>false</LEVEL_03>
        <LEVEL_04>false</LEVEL_04>
        <LEVEL_05>false</LEVEL_05>
        <LEVEL_06>false</LEVEL_06>
        <LEVEL_07>false</LEVEL_07>
        <LEVEL_08>false</LEVEL_08>
        <LEVEL_09>false</LEVEL_09>
        <LEVEL_10>false</LEVEL_10>
        </LEVEL>;;
        //file.deleteFile();
        var file:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("LevelsSaved.xml");

        if (file.exists)
        {
            trace("EXISTS");
            trace(GameSaveXML);
        }
        else
        {


            var fileStream = new FileStream();
            fileStream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);

            var outputString:String = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n';
            outputString +=  GameSaveXML.toXMLString();

            fileStream.writeUTFBytes(outputString);

            //GameSaveXML.replace(2,<LEVEL_03>true</LEVEL_03>);
            trace(GameSaveXML);
            fileStream.close();
            trace("File Was Created");
        }
    }
```

I'm really struggling with loading the file and checking what levels are unlocked (true) and what levels are still locked (false). Can you please help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Since it's for iOS do you have an option to use plist or json? For reading and writing xml you can try using [GDataXML](http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml)

Comment: Besides your XML structure can be improved. Since you want to save levels, the best way would be `<LEVELS>
 <LEVEL>
  <NUM>1</NUM>
  <UNLOCKED>false</UNLOCKED>
 </LEVEL>
 <LEVEL>
  <NUM>2</NUM>
  <UNLOCKED>false</UNLOCKED>
 </LEVEL>
</LEVELS>`

Comment: @Anupdas: Thank you but I'm writing it in AS3 and the GDataXML seems to be for xcode...

Comment: Sorry for that, but you can surely format your XML to a better one.

Comment: @Anupdas: I surely can and thanks for the tip. However it's not much of use if I don't know how to load and read the file :-)

Comment: I hope someone can guide in the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to write xml, can't you read it the same way?

```
    var content:String = fileStream.readUTFBytes(fileStream.bytesAvailable);
    var xml:XML = new XML(content);
    if (xml.LEVEL_01 == 'true') trace('unlocked');
    else trace('locked');
```

or you can use URLLoader to load xml as string

I'm 99% sure I did not undestand the question - sorry then :p